Dockerで初回起動時に「Error establishing a database connection」
※他サイト(teratail)でも質問中です。
ローカルにDockerを使用してWordPressを設置しようとしています。
しかし、 http://localhost:8080 を開いても「Error establishing a database connection」と表示されてしまいます。
（開発環境）
M1 MacBook Air
Ventura 13.5.1
Docker 27.1.2
docker-compose.ymlは下記のように記載しています。
version: '4'

services:
   db_2:
     platform: linux/x86_64
     image: mysql:5.7
     container_name: db_2
     hostname: db_2
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: unless-stopped
     environment:
       - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=nj89td!4?psd
       - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
       - MYSQL_USER=pro3rbjwp
       - MYSQL_PASSWORD=nj89td!4?psd

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db_2
     image: wordpress:latest
     container_name: wordpress
     volumes:
      - ./wp:/var/www/html
     ports:
       - "8080:80"
     expose:
       - 80
     restart: unless-stopped
     environment:
       - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db_2
       - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=pro3rbjwp
       - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=wordpress
       - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=nj89td!4?psd
volumes:
    db_data:



compose.yaml の image: mysql:5.4 を 8.0 に変更後、再度やり直してみると改善されました。

